# Call method on generic class

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have the following class and I want to call the `Get` method on this class. The problem is that I dont't have the type `T`. I have the string name of type `T`, that's all.

What I want is some thing like: This class is also registered with structure map but I dont how I can use it in structuremap

```
string name ="FooClass";
//Get IBaseCodeService<FooClass> then call Get method
public class BaseCodeService<T> : IBaseCodeService<T> where T : BaseCode
    {
        readonly IAttributeUow uow;
        public BaseCodeService(IAttributeUow uow)
        {
            this.uow = uow;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get()
        {
            using (uow)
            {

                var repo = uow.GetCoreRepository<T>();
                return await repo.GetAll().ToListAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a good duplicate because "calling a generic method using reflection" does not use the same code as "calling a method on a generic type using reflection".

Comment: So you want to create a BaseCodeService<T> of type "FooClass"? If that is the case, you could use Type.GetType(string).

Comment: but that foo class is in different project which means different assembly